# Convert date (month, day, year, time) to Datetime format in python

Tags: python, datetime

For a project, I'm fetching data from Salesforce and MongoDB and comparing field by field. The issue is the dates in MongoDB are stored in a string such as `"Apr 15, 2016, 4:08:03 AM"`. The same field is stored in as DateTime datatype in Salesforce such as `"2016-04-15T04:08:03.000+0000"`. I'm trying to convert either one of these fields to match with other format in python so I can compare them

So far, I have this

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
print(str(datetime_object)) #'2005-06-01 13:33:00'
```

Comment: `datetime.strptime` already gives you a datetime instance. What's your question?

Comment: How do I convert "2016-04-15T04:08:03.000+0000" to "Apr 15, 2016, 4:08:03 AM". Or vice versa?

Comment: You don't need to convert to strings to compare. If the field has type datetime in the database, then unless you're doing something odd, you'll get a datetime instance when you do a query. You can compare datetime instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on comparing as strings...

```
from datetime import datetime

a = "2016-04-15T04:08:03.000+0000"
b = "Apr 15, 2016, 4:08:03 AM"

a = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
b = datetime.strptime(b, '%b %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p')
b = b.replace(tzinfo=a.tzinfo)

print(a.isoformat())
print(b.isoformat())
```

Comment: Oops, I just noticed the time shift when I called `.astimezone` but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Justin. This was helpful.

Comment: Instead of `astimezone`, you can `replace` the tzinfo